# Using CONCAT in combination with SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, substr

I want to write a select that would return me a distinct years only (2018, 2017,2016).

I have column AS_OF_DATE in table HISTORY.

Here are some example values of AS_OF_DATE:

```
31-05-18,
31-04-17,
31-07-16,
...
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT CONCAT('20',DISTINCT SUBSTR(AS_OF_DATE, 7, 2) FROM HISTORY
```

I used CONCAT to add 20 in front of the result and SUBSTR that would start at the 7th string and would be 2 strings long (so I get 18,17,16...)

Comment: date are stored as date datatype or string?? it should be stored as data optimally!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT '20' || SUBSTR(AS_OF_DATE, 7, 2) FROM HISTORY
```

Comment: It works !  How would I select only results that are smaller than INPUT_PARAMETER_YERS? 

SELECT DISTINCT '20' ||  SUBSTR(AS_OF_DATE, 7, 2) AS RESULT FROM HISTORY WHERE RESULT < $INPUT_PARAMETER_YEARS;

Comment: @korodani no you can not use result alias you need use where extract(year from as_of_date)<INPUT_PARAMETER_YEARS

Comment: @korodani or use where SUBSTR(AS_OF_DATE, 7, 2)<INPUT_PARAMETER_YEARS

Comment: yes apparently alias can't be used for comparision.  I used your solution and it worked, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191865/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-korodani).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would do this with `extract()` or `to_char()`:

```
select extract(year from as_of_date) as yyyy
```

or

```
select to_char(as_of_date, 'YYYY') as yyyy
```

This assumes that `as_of_date` is a date, which is should be.

You can add `select distinct` if you want a result set with the distinct years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  SELECT CONCAT('20', SUBSTR(AS_OF_DATE, -2) ) as "Years"
    FROM HISTORY
   GROUP BY SUBSTR(AS_OF_DATE, -2)
   ORDER BY "Years"
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/QVEF58411)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select distinct extract(year from as_of_date) from History;
```

the `extract` function takes off the `as_of_date` provided it is a  `date` datatype and `distinct` select only one for dates which are multiple times in the extract.